# I split from Python, but the data I import is different for each log file. Can't we solve it through regular expressions or if statements?

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

Split was performed to obtain the desired value, but each log has a different value.

Can I get only the data I want using the regular expression or if condition?

ex)
Log
0xfe2324 : Wafer = 1351, wzm = 5215, tilt = 3167
It is expressed in this way, but sometimes the location is slightly different, so the a log file takes the wafer value 1351 b log file 5215.
I want to bring only the value of 5215 for wzm.

```
for i in data:
 if '0xfe2324' in i:
  test = i.split(',')[44]
  print(test)
```

please..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
^(?=0xfe2324).*wzm\s*=\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ev5iBo/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?=0xfe2324)` - the text next to the right must be `0xfe2324`
- `.*` - consumes any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `wzm` - a fixed string
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

In Python:

```py
import re
text = "your text here"
matches = re.findall(r'^(?=0xfe2324).*wzm\s*=\s*(\w+)', text, re.M)
print(matches)
```